# Calling methods from a running Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, runnable

So I am trying to make a music player that runs on a separate thread. I want to have methods inside of the Player class (that implements Runnable) to pause, play and go to next/prev song. If I was to call inner methods of the Thread, would it still run on a separate thread? Everything works as it should, but I am still new to Threads so I'm not sure if this is good practice or not. Could someone shed some light on this?

```
class Player implements Runnable, OnCompletionListener {
    public static final String TAG = "Player";
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;
    private SongsManager sm = null;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private int currentSongIndex = 0;

    public Player(int currentSongIndex){
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        sm = new SongsManager();
        songsList = sm.getSongList();
        this.currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(currentSongIndex).get(SongsManager.KEY_PATH));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            isPlaying = true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void pause() {
        if (isPlaying){
            if (mp != null){
                mp.pause();
                isPlaying = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void play() {
        if (!isPlaying){
            if (mp != null){
                mp.start();
                isPlaying = true;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

So say, if I created a new Thread like so,

```
Player player = new Player(0);
playerThread = new Thread(player, Player.TAG);
playerThread.start();
```

and called player.pause(), then player.play() from a different thread, would the player still be running on the separate thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I was to call inner methods of the Thread, would it still run on a separate thread?

No.  Threads aren't magic.  When you call a method you are calling that method with the current thread.  To fork a thread you actually have to create a thread object (or executor service) and start it.  Then it calls `run()`, etc..

So if you called `player.pause()` you would be calling pause from the current thread which is possibly the "main" thread.  Your `playerThread` would be doing something else in the background.  The whole reason why the `pause()` method is `synchronized` is so you can all it from the outside thread *and* the `playerThread` without them overlapping.  It also means that multiple threads can test and set the `isPlaying` boolean and other threads will see the updates.

You should most likely start with the [Java thread tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: okay thanks; so if instead of having mp.pause()/.start() in the synchronized methods, I just called the Player.pause() and Player.start() methods, then made a new Thread(player, TAG).start(), this would accomplish my goal?

Comment: Seems like are you confused @ChrisMcJava.  If you are calling `Player.start()` then `start()` needs to be `static`.  When you synchronize on a `static` method you are synchronizing on the `Player.class` object which probably not what you want.

Comment: sorry my mistake I did not mean Player.start(); Allow me to rephrase:
so, after player has been instantiated, and a new player thread has been made ( Thread playerThread = new Thread(player, TAG).start(); ), then from the main ui thread, player.pause() is called, what if I just omitted the player.play() method, and made a new Thread ( Thread playerThread = new Thread(player, TAG).start() ) when the play button was pressed from the UI? I think this will work

Answer (score 1):

The content of the `run()` method is what executes on the separate thread. Anything that calls a method of of the class that contains `run()` will execute that method on its own thread. You must therefore insure that any data access is properly thread-safe.